# Why does this mock api not work as expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to test this simple api module:

```js
import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch';

export const getJson = (endpoint: string) => {
  const options = { credentials: 'include', method: 'GET' };

  return fetch(endpoint, options)
    .then(response => response.json()
      .then(json => {
        if (response.ok) return json;
        return Promise.reject(json.errors);
      })
    )
    .catch(error => {
      if (error.constructor === Array) return error;
      return [error.message];
    });
};
```

With this test, where I'm mocking fetch:

```js
import { getJson } from '../api';

const mockResponse = (status, statusText, response) => {
  return new window.Response(response, {
    status: status,
    statusText: statusText,
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
};

describe('api middleware', () => {
  describe('getJson', () => {
    it('should return the response on success', () => {
      const expected = { data: ['data'], meta: {} };
      const body = JSON.stringify(expected);

      window.fetch = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() =>
        Promise.resolve(mockResponse(200, null, body)));

      return getJson('http://endpoint').then(actual => expect(actual).toEqual(expected));
    });
  });
});
```

But the test fails with:

```
Expected value to equal:
  {"data": ["data"], "meta": {}}
Received:
  ["Unexpected end of JSON input"]

Difference:

Comparing two different types of values:
  Expected: object
  Received: array
```

I've not been able to figure out why this isn't working. Why am I receiving the "Unexpected end of JSON input" error? And how do I successfully mock fetch locally in a test? In [this medium post](https://medium.com/@ferrannp/unit-testing-with-jest-redux-async-actions-fetch-9054ca28cdcd) it's done in basically the same way..

Comment: I had a mock of `isomorphic-fetch` at the root of the project. If I remove that the test result is: `["request to http://endpoint failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND endpoint endpoint:80"]`. So it seems jest was using that mock automatically. However, fetch has still not been replaced by my mock implementation.

Comment: Maybe cause the you have to use `global` instead of `window`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the test was still using the global fetch library, and not my patched version. The solution was to:

1. Remove the 'isomorphic-fetch' mock (in `__mocks__` at the root of the project).
2. Import 'isomorphic-fetch' once at the root of my project with `import 'isomorphic-fetch;`
3. Remove the 'isomorphic-fetch' import at the top of my api module (since it's already imported at the entrypoint
4. Update the test to:

test:

```
// to make the Response constructor available
import 'isomorphic-fetch';
import { getJson } from '../api';

describe('api middleware', () => {
  describe('getJson', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
      window.fetch = jest.genMockFunction();
    });

    it('should return the response on success', () => {
      const expected = { data: ['data'], meta: {} };
      const body = JSON.stringify(expected);
      const init = { status: 200, statusText: 'OK' };

      window.fetch.mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve(new Response(body, init)));

      return getJson('http://endpoint').then(actual => expect(actual).toEqual(expected));
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It solved the problem I posted above.

Answer (score -1):

Most probably because your `getJson` function does not use the global (window) `fetch`.

The way I would suggest doing it is to use [Dependency Injection (DI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection); make `getJson` retrieve the the "http request" library/function (in your case `fetch`) and in your tests, create a mock function which is injected. The mock function will return the data that you want as part of testing.

Comment: You mean because it's imported from the isomorphic-fetch package?

Comment: If that's the problem, how would I then mock the fetch from isomorphic-fetch  from within the test?

Comment: Why the downvotes? As seen form the other answer what I described was exactly the reason why it didn't work. 

See my updated answer for more info on the solution.

Comment: I think because your answer was only one line in the beginning. Even though it might have been correct (I'm not sure). My answer was downvoted as well, so no idea..